# Slow query from getting the intersection of news_tags and users_tags

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, join

I have two tables: "news_tags" and "users_tags". Now I want to get the appropriate users for a particular news. I get the right results with my query, but it's so slow.

Here is my query so far:

```
SELECT `users_id`
FROM `users_tags`
WHERE `tags_id` IN (SELECT `tags_id` FROM `news_tags`
                    WHERE `news_id` = '$news_id')
GROUP BY `users_id`
ORDER BY `users_id`
```

Is there a way to do it much faster?

Many thanks an greets

Comment: Doesn't MySQL execute a `join` faster than `in`?

Comment: Are your columns indexed properly?

Comment: This sounds like a 1:many relationship?  1 news : many users?  But the table names sound like many:many?  (`user_tags` and `news_tags`)  What is the intent of the query?  And, let's see the `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting to an INNER JOIN will give you a boost.

```
SELECT `users_id` FROM `users_tags` u INNER JOIN news_tags t 
ON u.tags_id = t.tags_id 
WHERE `news_id` = '$news_id' GROUP BY `users_id` ORDER BY `users_id`
```

Then make sure that you have an index on the `news_id` column of `news_tags` and also an index on `tags_id` of `users_tags`

In fact a composite index on users_tags(tags_id, users_id) might be even better. All these will need to be decided after looking at your EXPLAIN output.

Comment: hi @e4c5 thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I'm getting an error:  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN news_tags t ON u.tags_id = t.tags_id WHERE `news_id` = '22') GROU' at line 1

Comment: sorry I had been careless. Please try now

Comment: thank you, it works now more than 23 times faster (I removed the closing bracket before).

Comment: oops another careless act by me. Glad it worked and all the best with your project

Comment: While I agree with this answer, I am puzzled as to what it is trying to do.